# Наследование в codeigniter 3.Сделать базовый контроллер который наследует CI_Controller. Как правильно организовать?

Tags: php, ооп, codeigniter, controller, множественное-наследование

Наследование в codeigniter 3. Прочитал документацию не смог понять. Есть у меня контроллер Trekking и он наследует CI_Controller.

```
class Trekking extends CI_Controller {}
```

И надо сделать чтоб другие контроллеры тоже могли  наследовать class Trekking.

```
class Main extends Trekking {}
```

Подскажите как это правильно организовать, чтоб методы в class Trekking могли были доступны и в других контроллерах. Еще в class Trekking могли передаваться параметры.

Comment: Какие именно параметры вы хотите передавать туда?

Comment: @Manitikyl переменные.Например: Id, дату итд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Крч, я не совсем разобрался как вы собираетесь передавать параметры, но знаю как делается кастомный контроллер.

У вас в папке `application` есть папка `core`, там создаем файлик `MY_Controller.php` с таким текстом:

```
<?php

class Trekking extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

И по идеи, должно все работать, если не заработает, напишите в комментарии я подправлю на второй вариант (а такой имеется).

По поводу параметров я не понял, но как-то так?)

```
class Trekking extends CI_Controller
{
    public $id = NULL

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

Теперь метод `setId` доступен у всех контроллеров которые унаследованы от `Trekking`

Comment: public function setId($id)
    {
        return $id;
    }        Будет доступен id если вызову setId в других контроллерах?

Comment: @Улан А как вы собрались одновременно вызвать 2 контроллера? :) По дефолту в `CI` так не позволяет делать.

Comment: не так поняли, допустим есть контроллер main и он наследуется Trecking. Внутри Trecking есть методы которые что-то возвращают с помощью return. Будет ли доступны в main эти return ы?

Comment: @Улан Конечно, т.е. в нашем случае, у контроллера `main` по дефолту уже будет функция `$this->setId()` он может как принимать так и задавать что-то

Comment: И обязательно MY_Controller.php называть? Как я понимаю название папки и название класса должны совпадать? или в  этом случае не так?

Comment: В этом случае не так, обязательно, если хотите называть по другому, то `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` меняем, на `Base_` и теперь файл можете называть `Base_controller`

Comment: Помогли... буду знать

Comment: @Улан обращайтесь ;)